# Bitmap Size Exceed VM budget In android

Tags: android

In my android app i have set the image on ImageView capture by camera. its working fine. but when i capture image and back to the screen with setting that image on imageview and if i do this 3 to 4 time i got This ERROR BITMAP SIZE EXCEEDS VM BUDGETS ...................please need any solution for it.

```
this is my code below :

 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 options.inSampleSize = 4;
                 options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
                 image_from_camera.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                 "/sdcard/"+chore_string+".jpg", options));

i have done using bitmap.recycle(); or System.gc();
```

but this is not working . i need to have free the memory from bitmap when again camera button click to take second picture in app.  PLEASE NEED ANY HELP........

THANKS. ...

Answer (score 1):

increasing the value of the inSampleSize will decrease the memory overhead required to load the image. Change it to 8,12 or 16... and the image should eventually load but it might not look very good.

However, it seems like you might be using a good bit of memory prior to the load.

Use System.getRuntime() to get the runtime and then see what your max memory, total memory and free memory are to better understand how much space you have.

It's possible you are leaking memory prior to this allocation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html

also (annoyingly) if you are using a device that can't run android 3.0 not all of the memory used will show up in the runtime calls. consider using a 3.0 device to more fully understand the memory usage.